# QListView - slows with very long lines

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside2

I am logging data into a `QListView` and that can include lines with ~130K characters in a given line! Putting aside why that's needed, what I've found is that the extremely long lines cause slow downs (for example, when scrolling in the list view).

Below is a simple example of loading a file (not quite the same as I'm logging live traffic). If I load a file with just **a few** very long lines, I see the slow performance AFTER the loading is complete.

Conversely, I can load the same file and slice the lines (limit line length) and it loads fairly quickly and, more importantly, the UI is very responsive to scrolling, etc.

Is there a setting or method to overcome this issue? I know it's possible because [klogg](https://github.com/variar/klogg/) can load the same file without any issues (in terms of loading AND scrolling, etc performance). I just can't figure out how they do it. I know they don't load the entire file into memory which is why tested with just loading a few long lines to compare a small 'window' of long lines.

I have also tried creating my own custom `QAbstractListModel` but performance was the same.

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QApplication, QListView
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem

class ListDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.resize(1000,940)

        self.listview = QListView()
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.listview.setModel(self.model)
        self.listview.setUniformItemSizes(True) # <---Not sure I can use this as lines are all different lengths (lose horizontal scrollbar)
        # self.listview.setWrapping(False)
        self.load_lv = QPushButton("Load File LV")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.listview)
        layout.addWidget(self.load_lv)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.load_lv.clicked.connect(self.loadfile_lv)

    def loadfile_lv(self):
        with open('new 6.txt') as file: # This has very long lines...
            ctr = 0
            lines = []
            for line in file:
                lines.append(line.rstrip()) # <--- Change to line[:10000].rstrip() and no issues
                ctr+=1
                if ctr>100000:
                    break
            for l in lines:
                self.model.appendRow(QStandardItem(l))


    def closeEvent(self, event):
            print("CLOSE EVENT")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = ListDemo()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The slow response time is probably caused by the attempt from Qt to elide text in order to show the contents in a readable and usable way, or to display the items in their full width (since it needs to pass through *all* items in order to get the size hint).

With lines that long, both are clearly problematic.

Since the basic display will never need so many characters, you should set the `DisplayRole` (the default) with a limited, reasonable amount of characters, while keeping the original data using [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditem.html#setData) and eventually custom role.

Then, whenever you need to access the full contents of each line, just use `data()`.

In the following example, I'm using the first 500 characters of the line, which should be fine in any normal situation, having an estimate size of ~3000 pixels on a standard font size. If the log view is not supposed to be too wide, you can even reduce that amount to 100-200 characters.

```py
    def loadfile_lv(self):
        with open('new 6.txt') as file:
            ctr = 0
            lines = []
            for line in file:
                line = line.rstrip()
                item = QStandardItem(line[:500])
                item.setData(line) # defaults to UserRole+1
                self.model.appendRow(item)

                ctr+=1
                if ctr>100000:
                    break

    def get_line_content(self, line_nr):
        return self.model.item(line_nr).data()
```

You can also enforce the width by disabling the horizontal scroll bar, and disabling the text elision completely:

```py
    self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.view.setTextElideMode(Qt.ElideNone)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to Qt so not sure I fully understand. This is truncating the visible data so if the user scrolls to the right, they don't get to see all the data. Am I supposed to use `get_line_content` to somehow update all visible lines with all full data? Even if I could (not sure how) my testing has shown even a few lines of very long data causes slow down. Is this how klogg handles it?(sorry, I understand you may not be able to look at that code).

Comment: It's supposed to only show a limited amount of characters. It could be improved to show more characters, but considering that with an amount of 130k characters it would be anyway impossible to properly *scroll* the content, I wouldn't see the relevance, since it would be the only meaning of scrolling and would be almost unusable. Consider that the example you report (klogg) does *not* seem to use an item view, but a specialized text viewer, which clearly makes more sense to display *text files* and is probably what you should consider in place of QListView: for instance, QPlainTextEdit.

Comment: I would like the user to be able to scroll and see the data if they choose to. I originally had QPlainTextEdit but performance is much worse in terms of adding (loading) the data which is why I changed to QListView. Once loaded, QPlainTextEdit performance is much better.

Comment: Then I strongly suggest you to stick with QPlainTextEdit. The users won't mind a few seconds loading (maybe just add a loading dialog), but *will* mind a poor performance in browsing the text.

Comment: OK, I guess I will need to go back to that but normally I am logging 'live' so cannot put a loading dialog. My real testing showed it was really slow (whole UI became unresponsive) when inserting these long lines (even when buffered).

Comment: I'm afraid that even QPlainTextEdit would struggle with that kind of content: it's primarily intended to show "long" text, but not *that* wide. I gave a fast reading through klogg's code, and it actually doesn't even use a Qt doc viewer: it's a QAbstractScrollArea with customized painting that uses cached QPixmaps by splitting the contents in "chunks". Memory-wise, it might not seem optimal, but it's certainly effective: drawing text is complex and costly in terms of performance, especially against a bunch of pre-rendered and buffered pixels. Unfortunately, implementing that is not easy.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to look through klogg. Sounds like whatever I choose is either a bit of a compromise or some complex handling! I think I'll take a look at Wireshark code (also Qt based) see if I can find anything in there!

Comment: One other question - do you know if QML ListView would handle this better (I believe I can use QML with QWidgets)?

Comment: @SimpleOne I can't give you a valid answer as I've never actively used QML. Theoretically, it **could** be an improvement against the QWidget way: QWidgets geometries and painting are done through the QStyle interface, which can be a huge bottleneck (an item view generally calls dozens of QStyle functions for *each item* it displays), while QML uses basic primitives (geometric shapes). But QML is also a very high level API, and implementing a more complex UI as your case would need could mean that you're just moving the problem elsewhere. The pixmap approach seems promising, though.

Comment: I understand that your issue might seem "easy", but, in reality, it isn't, at least considering the general approach for which a "common API" is normally implemented for. When an API is created, it's generally developed considering common scenarios: text files with lots of lines (not lines of extreme length), or models with lots of items (not items with lots of text). Coincidentally, very long text in a single line makes its laying out more difficult: the text rendering engine must compute *all* the characters in order to properly display them, even if the font is (theoretically?) monospace.

Comment: That's why the pixmap approach can be effective: it *assumes* that the font has a fixed width (QPlainTextEdit doesn't do that by default, for good reasons: for instance, the user might not even have *any* fixed width font installed), and can compute the layout of the text (and, therefore, its painting) more easily: it *knows* that if you scroll the view by a certain amount, the first and last visible characters will always be reliable, as their computation is *deterministic*: you scroll the view by `x`, and you know that you'll *always* see the characters of that line starting from `x`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254113/discussion-between-simpleone-and-musicamante).