# QTreeView - request different amounts of data from model

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside2

I am trying to overcome a problem related to showing very long data as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493735/qlistview-slows-with-very-long-lines). Basically incoming data (single row) can be >64KB* which can cause sluggish GUI performance.

I've found QTreeView performs much better than QListView. However, it's still a little slow and was hoping to optimise further. I've found QTreeView is really fast when data per row is more 'reasonable' (e.g. 10000 chars).

One thought I had (at least as an interim solution) was for the QTreeView to ask for slightly more data than the column width - this way I am not providing huge long lines to the view and the user sees an elide if there is more data. Then, if the user either changes the column width or selects item(s) (e.g. to copy), the QTreeView should update to pull in the extra required data.

**Questions**: Is there a way to get QTreeView to ask for data based on column width (plus a bit extra so elide is shown if needed)? And, can I get QTreeView to then ask for the full data for any selected items?

Currently it is just one column but would be interested to know if it can be done to accommodate multiple columns (but not strictly required).

I am working in Python but happy to see suggestions in C++.

*Not all rows are this long. So, for smaller data, the user may indeed want to see all the data or copy it. So I want to have those options available and want it to be correct even for long data (e.g. copy should always return all data).

**Edit**:
For the first part (get `QTreeView` to ask for only enough data to fit the column). I connect to `sectionResized`, which provides column size, and use that to work out number of chars that will fit in the column (call it `max_width`). I pass that to the model and, whenever `data()` is called it returns data up to the `max_width`. That works nicely (not sure it is correct method though) and it means performance is really good.

But I cannot work how to get the view to refresh with the 'remaining' data when the user makes a selection. I know if I was to show the data in a different widget, I could get that to get the full data for the given row. But, it would be good if I could just get the current selection to refresh with the full data on selection.

Comment: What is the use-case for ***displaying*** all the data? Do you really expect users to scroll sidways to view/edit a 64kb string? That equates to about 100 lines of text (assuming a 60 char width) crammed in a single row. It would seem much more sensible to *display* a much shorter elided string, and store the full text using a separate data-role. This can then be supplied on demand (which implies custom copy handling and a custom viewer/editor). From a practical point of view, as a user I would be very disappointed if it didn't work that way.

Comment: That is part of what I am asking...I *do* want to elide the data and not display it all. BUT, my testing shows that even when the view just loads a few 64KB strings into the view (elided due to column width), it starts to get sluggish. So, what I'm asking is how to give the view less data (X chars per row max) but have that data available 'on demand' - e.g. on column width change or copy request

Comment: Essentially I want the user to know there is more data (by the elide) but not actually load it into view so I get the performance benefit. I assume for the elide to show, the view needs to get >column width of data from the model. Then, if the user wants to see more data (changes col width) or copy it, then I want to know how I can get the view to load more chars for those lines.

Comment: The intention is to *permanently* elide the text before assigning it to the display role. Expanding it dynamically is just trying have your cake and eat it, and allows the horrendous performance issues to creep back in. Just pick a reasonable *fixed* width and stick with it. If the user wants to see more, they can ask for it. Tables are designed for showing *tabular data*, which by definition, does not include huge strings. Very few users expect to see such data fully displayed inline, and the rest will hate you for killing performance by trying to do so.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding because it's not the displaying of the text that is causing the issue. My original implementation keeps the column unchanged and elides the data (showing <100 chars) but it seems Qt still loads the full 64KB (at least I'm assuming it does as the performance is sluggish; or it has to do some expensive calc due to long data). Are you saying there is a way to stop that? That's why I was trying to truncate the data returned by `data()`. And, can you please give an example of how user would ask for more data (I agree unlikely)?

Comment: Just re-read your comment: "before assigning it to the display role." So, you're saying always return a fixed length that is both good for performance but ensures the elide is shown (guess need to take into account hi-res displays that could display lots of chars). And, I guess in terms of asking for more data you mean something like user clicks/double-clicks and data shows in a widget/popup/whatever?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. One way or another, the only way to improve performance is to display less data *all at once* in the view. If you can use a fixed length (maybe 1000 chars) that is wider than the screen (but without impacting performance), it's hard to see how the user would even notice the difference. And I don't see how you can avoid using a separate widget to show the full text. For example, when copying a portion of the text that is wider than the screen, line-wrapping and vertical scrolling would seem essential (from a usability point of view).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254141/discussion-between-simpleone-and-ekhumoro).